# Sharepoint Workflow (2010) Attachment with macros not working

Tags: 2010, workflow

I have a workflow associated with a library and it sends an email with HTTP attachment (Excel). If the document has no macros attached, the receiver is able to open up the document with no issue. If it does have a macro, excel says the file is corrupt and will not open the document. Any fixes to this issue? Thanks!

Comment: So the workflow is sending Macro enabled documents from a document library via email to users and they are unable to open the documents?  If you download the file manually, do you have the same issue?  If not, are the working and non-working documents the same size?

Comment: Yes. They can see the documents, but when they go to open the document, it says the file is corrupt. If I go to the Sharepoint site where they are located, I can open them with no issue and the macro works just fine.

Comment: If I download the file manually off of the email, I get the same error message.

Comment: Can you determine any difference in the files? such as the size or more importantly, checksum?

Comment: The only difference I have been able to find so far is .xlsm vs. .xlsx.

Comment: The documents I am trying to send are roughly 1.3 mb

Comment: If you take a corrupt document that is .xlsx and rename the extension .xlsm  (the m in xlsm denotes Excel with macro), does it work?  I'd also like to see pictures of your SPD workflow, especially the details around email piece.

Comment: WF Line - Send non urgent email to ..., display ... as sender. Also attach file named [%Current Item:name%].[%Current Item.File Type%] retrieved from [%Current Item:Encoded Absolute URL%].

Comment: I am no longer 100% sure that the macros are the issue. My new thinking is either size type or old versions of excel.